# Keep min or max based on character in another column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have this tbl:

```
  Genes strand mode_position
    1:   2L52.1      +          1638
    2:   2L52.1      +          2096
    3:   npr-30      +          3156
    4:   homt-1      -          6081
    5:  B0348.5      +          6383
```

If there are duplicated Genes and the stand is +, I need to keep the row with the mode_position with highest value and if -, the row with the lowest value. So for 2L52.1, it should only keep row 2.
I was trying  `group_by(Genes) %>% if_else("strand" == "+", slice_max(mode_position, n=1))` but that obviously doesn't work because 'condition' has to be a logical vector.
case_when doesn't work on characters? What are some other options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if`/`else` with `which.max` and `which.min` to get max and min row.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Genes) %>%
  slice(if(all(strand == '+')) which.max(mode_position) 
        else which.min(mode_position)) %>%
  ungroup

#  Genes   strand mode_position
#  <chr>   <chr>          <int>
#1 2L52.1  +               2096
#2 B0348.5 +               6383
#3 homt-1  -               6081
#4 npr-30  +               3156
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Genes = c("2L52.1", "2L52.1", "npr-30", "homt-1", 
"B0348.5"), strand = c("+", "+", "+", "-", "+"), mode_position = c(1638L, 
2096L, 3156L, 6081L, 6383L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```